# Ubuntu 16.10 freezes randomly

Tags: 16.04, 16.10

My Dell XPS 8700 with Ubuntu 16.10 freezes randomly after some minutes, all SSH sessions are hung, screen freezes and mouse does not move. Even the cursor does not blink anymore on terminal. I have installed drivers for graphic Card from NVIDIA but to no avail. Please can someone help in resolving this issue.

Comment: not a solution, but if possible try to use an LTS version like `16.04.2`  which is superior and stable in almost every way than your os version `16.10`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you. Maybe your kernel is not working properly with the drivers you have to use. Try to install another kernel version and see if it helps. (Works most of the time).

An amazing program for doing that is [Ukuu](https://fossbytes.com/install-upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu-mint-ukuu/).

First add the repositories:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
```

Now update them:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the program:

```
sudo apt-get install ukuu
```

And then launch it from the launchpad or via the terminal by:

```
sudo ukuu-gtk
```

[image]

Inside the program, you can choose the kernel you want. Then, it downloads and installs it.
As the program indicates, those are the common errors that you have, caused by a non compatible kernel.

Hope it helps...